# Android Gradle build issues w/ Dagger

Tags: android, maven, gradle, dagger

I'm trying to migrate an Android project from Maven to Gradle (and Eclipse to Android Studio).  The project is large contains multiple modules.  The main reason for the switch is to get Multidex support.

To get my feet wet with Gradle I've tried to isolate and build a 'framework' module used by all of the other modules.

Here is the `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

description = 'Framework Implementation'

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.squareup.dagger', name: 'dagger', version:'1.2.2'
    compile(group: 'com.squareup.dagger', name: 'dagger-compiler',     version:'1.2.2') {
        exclude(module: 'guava')
    }
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-core-asl', version:'1.9.13'
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-asl', version:'1.9.13'
    compile group: 'com.github.tony19', name: 'logback-android-core', version:'1.0.10-2'
    compile group: 'com.github.tony19', name: 'logback-android-classic', version:'1.0.10-2'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version:'1.7.5'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.android', name: 'spring-android-rest-template', version:'2.0.0.M2'
    compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp', name: 'okhttp', version:'2.5.0', classifier:'COMPANY'
    compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp', name: 'okhttp-urlconnection', version:'2.5.0', classifier:'COMPANY'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version:'4.3.5'
    testCompile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version:'1.0.9'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.11'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version:'1.9.5'
    testCompile group: 'org.robolectric', name: 'robolectric', version:'2.2'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version:'1.6.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito', version:'1.6.1'
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Tried to build using `gradlew.bat --build` and I am getting the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':co-framework:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$VarSymbol cannot be cast to javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
```

The stacktrace shows:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':co-framework:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:62)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:155)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:152)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:33)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:100)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:94)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:94)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$VarSymbol cannot be cast to javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:469)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:132)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:45)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:33)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:101)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:34)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:157)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:139)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:93)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:243)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:230)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$VarSymbol cannot be cast to javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
at dagger.internal.codegen.ModuleAdapterProcessor.providerMethodsByClass(ModuleAdapterProcessor.java:172)
at dagger.internal.codegen.ModuleAdapterProcessor.process(ModuleAdapterProcessor.java:98)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
at     com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
at     com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
... 78 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.957 secs
```

Has anyone come across this before? Any ideas?

Java:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this article - http://www.frankdu.com/blog/2013/11/20/gradle-dagger-compiler-code-generation-for-android-library-and-app-projects/

After applying these changes and adding:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

It now builds successfully, albeit with a bunch of lint errors and what not. *shrugs*

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://github.com/square/dagger/issues/320) a discussion from the Dagger issue tracker.  Seems like dagger is hiding the actual error.  Remove the dagger-compiler dependency and you should see what the error is (seems to be caused by bad import or wildcard import of annotations)